# Efficiently remove first element in SortedSet<T>

Tags: c#, sortedset

I've got a SortedSet to which I'm adding items to (in an uncontrolled order, obviously making use of it's sorting abilities).

Items in the set are always used and removed in order, one at a time.

```
set.Min.Process();
set.Remove(set.Min);
```

The problem I'm facing however, is due to the O(log n) aspect of the Remove method, and the binary search nature of a SortedSet, this results in the maximum possible number of comparisons being made for each remove (~log n).

To me it seems weird that a collection based around accessing the min and max items wouldn't have an efficient way to remove them.

Effectively what I'm after is a set.RemoveMin() method, making use of the more optimized approach (comparison free) to get the first element.

Is there any way to do this?
Are there any existing alternative SortedSet implementations out there I could utilize?

Comment: Are you performing a lot of adds, then processing the set, then starting again? If so, you could build up the sorted set, then copy it to a linked list and process that instead.

Comment: You can't get the Min nor Max without walking the tree. Removing Min might require to rebalance the tree. This probably isn't the optimal data structure for your requirements.

Comment: If you want O(1) time accessing what it the problem if using simple array and sort this using Quick or Selection Sort depending on the how much your input is?

Comment: Adds and processing is done both at arbitrary speeds, so there is almost always some content in set. Essentially, I'm sorting some delegates by a 'call time', so items are getting added, then called when that time (a float) has been passed.

Comment: @CodeCaster the 'Min' is evaluated by traversing left, left, left... on the tree. There's no requirement for a comparison to ever be done. Likewise, unless i'm wrong, the rebalancing doesn't require comparisons either. Therefore to me, it seems inefficient to involve O(logn) comparisons to remove the min item.

Comment: @Randomman159 To me it sounds that adding, accessing and removing will be the most of the work while structure itself will not have many items due to processing, am I right?

Comment: Sounds like you need priority queue and not sorted set for what you are doing.

Comment: @kuskmen as it's a time based system, most items are not in there for more than 5 - 10 seconds, so it really depends on demand regarding the actual number of items in the system. Ideally I just want a collection which efficiently sorts (logn comparisons) when an item is added, but can, without comparison, efficiently access and remove the first item.

Comment: @Randomman159 then what I will suggest you is first knowing your domain, start this code that your have for like 1 day on your testing environment, make some statistics - how many items were in the structure, how many time it took to process when under pressure and relaxed environmentm THEN you make an assumption, because right now it looks like we are watching some table and we are saying - hey hey this data structure have O(logn)  and that algorithm have O(nlogn) time so both are good, right? NO. You know what is good after you know your domain. Don't forget big O is UPPER bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] I instrumented this and it doesn't seem faster than just using `SortedSet`, so this may not be a good answer!

@randomman159 - If this doesn't help after you've tried it out, please comment to this answer and I will delete it.

---

What you are describing is a [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Here's a basic implementation using a heap.

Its complexity is O(LogN) for both `Enqueue()` and `Dequeue()`:

```
/// <summary>Priority Queue data structure.</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Implemented in traditional fashion, using a heap.
/// Based on code from http://www.vcskicks.com/priority-queue.php
/// 
/// Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)
/// and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue
/// </remarks>

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1711:IdentifiersShouldNotHaveIncorrectSuffix")]

public sealed class PriorityQueue<T>
{
    /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
    /// <param name="comparer">A comparison function for items of type T>.</param>

    public PriorityQueue(Comparison<T> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
        _heap = new List<T> {default(T)};
    }

    /// <summary>The number of items in the queue.</summary>

    public int Count => _heap.Count - 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value at the head of the Priority Queue without removing it.
    /// Throws an exception if the queue is empty.
    /// </summary>

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (this.Count > 0)
        {
            return _heap[1]; // Head of the queue is at [1], not [0].
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to Peek() into an empty PriorityQueue<T>");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Adds a value to the Priority Queue</summary>

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        _heap.Add(value);
        this.bubbleUp(_heap.Count - 1); // Bubble up to preserve the heap property, starting at the inserted value.
    }

    /// <summary>Returns the front of the Priority Queue.</summary>

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.Count > 0)
        {
            T minValue = this._heap[1]; // The smallest value in the Priority Queue is the first item in the array

            if (this._heap.Count > 2) // If there's more than one item, replace the first item in the array with the last one.
            {
                T lastValue = this._heap[_heap.Count - 1];

                this._heap.RemoveAt(_heap.Count - 1);       // Move last node to the head
                this._heap[1] = lastValue;
                this.bubbleDown(1);
            }
            else  // Only one item in the queue.
            {
                _heap.RemoveAt(1);  // Remove the only value stored in the queue.
            }

            return minValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to Dequeue() from an empty PriorityQueue<T>");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Restores the heap-order property between child and parent values going up towards the head.</summary>

    private void bubbleUp(int startCell)
    {
        // Requires(startCell >= 0);
        // Requires(startCell < _heap.Count);

        int cell = startCell;

        while (this.isParentBigger(cell))   // Bubble up as long as the parent is greater.
        {
            // Get values of parent and child.

            T parentValue = this._heap[cell/2];
            T childValue  = this._heap[cell];

            // Swap the values.

            this._heap[cell/2] = childValue;
            this._heap[cell]   = parentValue;

            cell /= 2; // Go up parents.
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Restores the heap-order property between child and parent values going down towards the bottom.</summary>

    private void bubbleDown(int startCell)
    {
        // Requires(startCell > 0);
        // Requires(startCell < _heap.Count);

        int cell = startCell;

        // Bubble down as long as either child is smaller.

        while (this.isLeftChildSmaller(cell) || this.isRightChildSmaller(cell))
        {
            int child = this.compareChild(cell);

            if (child == -1) // Left Child.
            {
                // Swap values.

                T parentValue    = _heap[cell];
                T leftChildValue = _heap[2*cell];

                _heap[cell]   = leftChildValue;
                _heap[2*cell] = parentValue;

                cell = 2*cell; // Move down to left child.
            }
            else if (child == 1) // Right Child.
            {
                // Swap values.

                T parentValue     = _heap[cell];
                T rightChildValue = _heap[2*cell+1];

                _heap[cell]     = rightChildValue;
                _heap[2*cell+1] = parentValue;

                cell = 2*cell+1; // Move down to right child.
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Is the value of a parent greater than its child?</summary>

    private bool isParentBigger(int childCell)
    {
        // Requires(childCell >= 0);
        // Requires(childCell < _heap.Count);

        if (childCell == 1)
        {
            return false;  // Top of heap, no parent.
        }
        else
        {
            return _comparer(_heap[childCell/2], _heap[childCell]) > 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether the left child cell is smaller than the parent cell.
    /// Returns false if a left child does not exist.
    /// </summary>

    private bool isLeftChildSmaller(int parentCell)
    {
        // Requires(parentCell >= 0);
        // Requires(parentCell < _heap.Count);

        if (2*parentCell >= _heap.Count)
        {
            return false; // Out of bounds.
        }
        else
        {
            return _comparer(_heap[2*parentCell], _heap[parentCell]) < 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether the right child cell is smaller than the parent cell.
    /// Returns false if a right child does not exist.
    /// </summary>

    private bool isRightChildSmaller(int parentCell)
    {
        // Requires(parentCell >= 0);
        // Requires(parentCell < _heap.Count);

        if (2 * parentCell + 1 >= _heap.Count)
        {
            return false; // Out of bounds.
        }
        else
        {
            return _comparer(_heap[2*parentCell+1], _heap[parentCell]) < 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the children cells of a parent cell. -1 indicates the left child is the smaller of the two,
    /// 1 indicates the right child is the smaller of the two, 0 inidicates that neither child is smaller than the parent.
    /// </summary>

    private int compareChild(int parentCell)
    {
        // Requires(parentCell >= 0);
        // Requires(parentCell < _heap.Count);

        bool leftChildSmaller  = this.isLeftChildSmaller(parentCell);
        bool rightChildSmaller = this.isRightChildSmaller(parentCell);

        if (leftChildSmaller || rightChildSmaller)
        {
            if (leftChildSmaller && rightChildSmaller)
            {
                // Figure out which of the two is smaller.

                int leftChild  = 2 * parentCell;
                int rightChild = 2 * parentCell + 1;

                T leftValue  = this._heap[leftChild];
                T rightValue = this._heap[rightChild];

                // Compare the values of the children.

                if (_comparer(leftValue, rightValue) <= 0)
                {
                    return -1; // Left child is smaller.
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1; // Right child is smaller.
                }
            }
            else if (leftChildSmaller)
            {
                return -1; // Left child is smaller.
            }
            else
            {
                return 1; // Right child smaller.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; // Both children are bigger or don't exist.
        }
    }

    private readonly List<T>       _heap;
    private readonly Comparison<T> _comparer;
}
```

Add your elements using `Enqueue()` and remove the front elements by using `Dequeue()`.

Also see here for another implementation: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/11/01/Priority-Queues-with-C.aspx?Page=1

Comment: So how does that improve what the OP have so far?

Comment: @kuskmen It doesn't make the maximum number of comparisons (Log(N)) each time an element is removed. `Effectively what I'm after is a set.RemoveMin() method, making use of the more optimized approach (comparison free) to get the first element.`

Comment: Just skimming through now, it does still require comparisons during removal though? I'll look into whether it's more efficient for my needs though.

Comment: @Randomman159 Yes, it still requires comparisons during removal - I think the only way to know if this is an improvement is to instrument it.

Comment: @Randomman159 Also have a look at [the wiki page on priority queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and check the `Summary of running times` table for various implementations. Every implementation of `delete-min` has a complexity of `O(LogN)` so it seems like you're unlikely find something much faster.

Comment: I'll say it one more time, you need to know your domain, there are thousands of fancy algorithms and data structures that sucks at small input. Sometimes simplicity key. You are thinking of tree structure which means that access in memory will be almost certain not in order meaning it will slow you down, while if you use simple array memory collectors will actually move the next items you possibly will need in the CPU cache because of the nature of array (consecutive memory cells).

Comment: Awesome, thanks then. Regardless, I think is definitely the direction I want to be researching in. Thanks!

Comment: @kuskmen This is true, but the question doesn't specify that level of detail (e.g. the maximum queue size), so I provided a more general answer. The only way to know if it's an improvement is, like I said, to intstrument it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know, I am just trying to prevent people of making premature optimizations, but oh well.

Comment: @Randomman159 if it's crucial for your to make remove min to be O(1) - it's possible, but then adding new item will be O(n). Though I saw claims that it's possible to make add O(log n) and remove min O(1), but cannot confirm that.

Comment: @Randomman159 Well I've just instrumented this, and it looks like it IS NOT FASTER than just using `SortedSet<T>`. So this isn't really an answer!

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Yeah i've still been looking around. I'm yet to find a decent sorting collection that doesn't require comparisons within removal. Currently doing tests with this: https://github.com/BlueRaja/High-Speed-Priority-Queue-for-C-Sharp/